# How to write this ajax call in Python

Tags: python, ajax, request

I have a ajax call but I have to call it from a Python script. This is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    url: "saytts",
    data: {text: self.tts()}
});
```

I tried the package Requests but it's not working. Can someone translate this ajax call to a python request?

Thank you.

Comment: "but it's not working" what is not working? Show us some code.

Comment: this is the code I tried: `requests.post('saytts', data = {'text':'text'}, headers=headers)` and these are the headers: `headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
} `

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question that was answered on [Using Python, I want to pass a URL some json and get back data (imitating Podbean's jQuery/AJAX function)](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28961884/Using-Python-I-want-to-pass-a-URL-some-json-and-get-back-data-imitating-Podbean's-jQuery-AJAX-function.html). Based on that, your code might look like this:

```
import requests

url = "saytts"    
data = {"text": "text"}
result = requests.get(url, data)
print(result.status_code)
print(result.text)
```

Comment: Although this might also work:
    result = requests.get(url, json=data)